# Yii controller inheritance ( in submodule )

Tags: php, inheritance, yii, controller

My question is, how can I inherit Controllers action in YII, like:

```
class MainController extends FController
{
  public function ActionIndex()
  {
    $this->render("index"); //the view;
  }
}

--------------------------------------------
class SecondController extends FController
{
  public function ActiondIndex()
  {
   MainController::ActionIndex();   
  }
}
```

Actually in my case the SecondController is the DefaultController of a sub-module. I want to make single code based webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since PHP does not support multiple inheritance, you may access the base class via the parent keyword.

```
class MainController extends FController
{
  public function ActionIndex()
  {
    $this->render("index"); //the view;
  }
}

class SecondController extends FController
{
  public function ActionIndex() // Note: you mistyped the name of this action in your example
  {
    parent::ActionIndex();   
  }
}
```

Although you cannot reach the grandparent's `ActionIndex` method directly, you have to create a workaround for that.